# Compiled Querys in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, compiled, play-slick

I need to compile a query in Slick with Play and PostgreSQL

```scala
val bioMaterialTypes: TableQuery[Tables.BioMaterialType] = Tables.BioMaterialType

def getAllBmts() = for{ bmt <- bioMaterialTypes } yield bmt

val queryCompiled = Compiled(getAllBmts _)
```

but in Scala IDE I get this error in the Apply of Compiled

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Computation of type () => scala.slick.lifted.Query[models.Tables.BioMaterialType,models.Tables.BioMaterialTypeRow,Seq] 
 cannot be compiled (as type C)
- not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit compilable: scala.slick.lifted.Compilable[() => 
 scala.slick.lifted.Query[models.Tables.BioMaterialType,models.Tables.BioMaterialTypeRow,Seq],C], implicit driver: 
 scala.slick.profile.BasicProfile)C in object Compiled. Unspecified value parameters compilable, driver.
```

This are my imports:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.staticQueryToInvoker
import scala.slick.lifted.Compiled
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton
import models.BioMaterialType
import models.Tables
import play.api.Application
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.TableQuery
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.columnExtensionMethods
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.longColumnType
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.queryToAppliedQueryInvoker
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.queryToInsertInvoker
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.stringColumnExtensionMethods
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.stringColumnType
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.valueToConstColumn
import play.api.db.slick.DB
import play.api.db.slick.DBAction
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
val queryCompiled = Compiled(bioMaterialTypes)
```

Comment: I still got this errors:  could not find implicit value for parameter driver: scala.slick.profile.BasicProfile
 - not enough arguments for method apply